# Pyspark replacement of np.gradient

Tags: python, pyspark, derivative

I have a dataframe with two columns 'Timestamp', and 'Value'. I am calculating the the gradient of the dataframe using the following code:

```
df['slope'] = np.gradient(df['Value'])
```

However, I would like to make the switchover from using pandas to pyspark. I have searched online but could not find the equivalent code for a pyspark dataframe. Can someone please provide a suitable example? Many thanks.

Comment: I am quite late in answering this question; but you can leverage the Pandas on Spark API to accomplish this
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/pandas_on_spark/index.html